# Wordpress "do_shortcode" in custom page template

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I am trying to create a custom page template using a shortcode from this plugin [Shift Controller](http://shiftcontroller.com/)

The shortcode is "[shiftcontroller]" and it takes a location attribute so you can show shifts for a specific location like this: "[shiftcontroller location="2"]" where 2 is the location id. I have added a custom user filed called "locationid" so I can use that value with the shortcode to only show shifts for the specific location for the current user.

This is my page template code so far:

```
<?php
/*
Template name: Custom Shift Controller Page
*/
get_header(); ?>

<?php do_action( 'flatsome_before_page' ); ?>

<div id="content" role="main" class="content-area">

        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

            <?php
                $client_user = wp_get_current_user();
                $user_id = $client_user->ID;
                $key = 'locationid';
                $single = true;

                $client_location_id = get_user_meta( $user_id, $key, $single );

                echo '<h2 class="" style="text-align: center;">Manage, view and book shifts</h2>';
                echo '<h1>The Client Location ID: ' . $client_location_id . '</h1>';
                echo do_shortcode('[shiftcontroller location="' . $client_location_id . '"]');
                // echo do_shortcode('[shiftcontroller]');
                // echo apply_filters( 'the_content', '[shiftcontroller]');
            ?>

        <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

</div>

<?php do_action( 'flatsome_after_page' ); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I'm echoing the h1 so i can confirm the location id and it is working correctly. However, the shift calendar which should show is not showing at all. Even without my custom locationid code, just `echo do_shortcode('[shiftcontroller]');` is still not displaying the calendar.

Any ideas on why the shortcode won't work? The shift calendar uses AJAX but I don't know if that may be causing the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there in the commented code. You just have to apply the correct filters. Instead of using `echo do_shortcode();`, try:

```
echo apply_filters('the_content', '[shiftcontroller location="' . $client_location_id . '"]');
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Just tried that and it didn't work. Even without the locationid, `echo apply_filters( 'the_content', '[shiftcontroller]');` still doesnt work. The shortcode is not being computed/displayed at all for some reason.

Comment: If the content gets loaded in via ajax, can you check if you are receiving any javascript errors on the page?

Comment: If the `do_shortcode` and `apply_filters` weren't working, they would have returned the shortcode in plain text. i.e. "_[shiftcontroller location="XXX"]_" in your page content. This kinda points to there being an external problem (i.e. not with how you are calling your shortcode). I would suggest checking if the javascript files used by your shortcode are loading on the page and go from there. Good luck!

Comment: I think you might be onto something with the js files for the plugin. Let me go down that hole. Thanks for the help. Much appreciated

Comment: I've checked and the js files are not being called on my custom template. I know this digresses from the original question but is there a way of calling one plugin's files from a different plugin? Thanks again